# VBA: Nested loop giving me Error: Excel can only convert one column at a time

Tags: excel, vba, loops, nested-loops

Right now, I have a nested loop to extract stock prices from Google finance's API. 
It gets stored onto a sheet named 'Data', which after I write the Open and Close as Open~Close to another sheet Spread

I have a nested loop, however, I keep getting the error message that excel can only convert one column at a time. I've tried doing a number of things, but I keep getting the error message.

```
Sub GetData()
Dim DataSheet As Worksheet
Dim EndDate As Date
Dim StartDate As Date
Dim Symbol As String
Dim qurl As String
Dim nQuery As Name
Dim LastRow As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Sheets("Data").Cells.Clear


Set DataSheet = ActiveSheet

StartDate = DataSheet.Range("startDate").Value
EndDate = DataSheet.Range("endDate").Value
Sheets("Data").Range("a1").CurrentRegion.ClearContents

'my ops here'
Sheets("Spread").Cells.Clear

Dim Last As Integer
Last = DataSheet.Range("K6000").End(xlUp).Row
Dim j As Integer
For j = 2 To Last
        If j < Last Then
        Symbol = DataSheet.Range("K" & j).Value
'On my Sheet, I have a list of symbols down Column K'
'********'


qurl = "http://finance.google.com/finance/historical?q=" & Symbol
qurl = qurl & "&startdate=" & MonthName(Month(StartDate), True) & _
       "+" & Day(StartDate) & "+" & Year(StartDate) & _
       "&enddate=" & MonthName(Month(EndDate), True) & _
       "+" & Day(EndDate) & "+" & Year(EndDate) & "&output=csv"

QueryQuote:
With Sheets("Data").QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & qurl, Destination:=Sheets("Data").Range("a1"))
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .TablesOnlyFromHTML = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    .SaveData = True
End With


'Below is where I think the error start. I'm not sure if the loop get iterated here before my nested loop is done..'
Sheets("Data").Range("a1").CurrentRegion.TextToColumns Destination:=Sheets("Data").Range("a1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                                                       TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
                                                       Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, other:=False

Sheets("Data").Columns("A:H").ColumnWidth = 15

LastRow = Sheets("Data").UsedRange.Row - 2 + Sheets("Data").UsedRange.Rows.Count




Sheets("Data").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A" & LastRow), _
                                   SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

With Sheets("Data").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:G" & LastRow)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
    .SortFields.Clear
End With

'My ops here'
Sheets("Spread").Cells(1, j) = Symbol
Dim k As Integer
k = Sheets("Data").Range("A1", Sheets("Data").Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count


Dim i As Integer
For i = 2 To k - 1
If i < k - 1 Then
Sheets("Spread").Cells(i, j) = Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 2) & "~" & Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 5)
End If
Next i


End If
Next j
'Here is where I have a nested loop'

End Sub
```

Comment: `Sheets("Data").Range("a1").CurrentRegion` will select all content beginning at A1  - same as selecting A1 then pressing Ctrl+A.  If that's more than one column wide then Text to Columns will not run. `Sheets("Data").Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1)` should operate only on the first column.

Comment: also I'm not sure that you need `TextToColumns` at all. Why do you need that?